# How to manually install software without breaking APT?

Tags: installation, apt

I need automake-1.12.2, however, the most recent automake in my apt-get is 1.11.x. I have downloaded and compiled the latest automake. 
How do I install it without breaking the current installation and messing up with APT ?

I am using Debian 7 stable.

Comment: On which operating system are you solving the problem? (most probably Linux) Which distribution? Which version? Most probably it will suffice to install `automake` from a newer repository. I will remove my -1 after you add the missing information.

Comment: Does it make a difference ? APT is for Debian and its derivative only anyway... I'm using Debian 7.

Comment: I think that this makes difference. There are different repositories available for different OSs. Also Debian is available in different flavours. There is [Debian GNU/kFreeBSD](http://www.debian.org/ports/kfreebsd-gnu/). --- I am also not sure what do you mean by *... wihtout ... messing up with APT". If you mean that you want to ignore APT then it is not a good idea. --- Could you please add the information to the question to make it a better question? It is not a good idea to leave it just in comments.